# How to calculate the total from each cycles by using igraph in R?

Tags: r, sum, igraph, cycle, calculation

I have a data frame which is as below :

```
h = data.frame(fr  = c('A','A','X','E','B','W','C','Y'),
               t   = c('B','E','Y','C','A','X','A','W'),
               Amt = c( 40, 30, 55, 10, 33, 78, 21, 90))
```

I've found all the possible vertex sequence that starts with the smallest vertex number
by using [r igraph find all cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091438/r-igraph-find-all-cycles) as reference.
And the result is as below :

```
[[1]]
A E C A 
1 3 6 1 

[[2]]
A B A 
1 4 1 

[[3]]
X Y W X 
2 7 5 2
```

---

Now I'd like to

- calculate the sum from each cycles
- numbers of edges in each cycles

It'd be like this :

**A - B - A**  :  40 + 33 = 73 ; numbers of edges : 2

**A - E - C - A** : 30 + 10 + 21 = 61 ; numbers of edges : 3

**X - Y - W - X** : 55 + 90 + 78 = 223 ; numbers of edges : 3

Does anyone have any ideas to use R to calculate? That would be great appreciation !!

---

**FURTHER EDIT PART**

Thanks to the reply, I can calculate two items above !!
However, I got a tiny problem here !!

I don't know what the problem I got so that I cannot calculate correctly !!
Even I modify many times.

It should be like this :

```
[[1]]        [[2]]     [[3]]
A E C A      A B A     X Y W X

  Path            sumAmt numberOfEdges
  <fct>            <dbl>         <int>
1 "A - B - A"         73             2
2 "A - E - C - A"     61             3
3 "X - Y - W - X"    223             3
```

But After I put in my code, it cannot show up the first node :

```
[[1]]        [[2]]     [[3]]
  E C A        B A       Y W X

  Path            sumAmt numberOfEdges
  <fct>            <dbl>         <int>
1 " - B - A"         33             2
2 " - E - C - A"     31             3
3 " - Y - W - X"    168             3
```

Here's my code on finding cycles. Does anything I miss to put-in ??

```
h = data.frame(fr  = c('A','A','X','E','B','W','C','Y'),
               t   = c('B','E','Y','C','A','X','A','W'),
               Amt = c( 40, 30, 55, 10, 33, 78, 21, 90))

library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(h, directed = TRUE)

Cycles = NULL
for(fr in V(g)) {
  for(t in neighbors(g, fr, mode = "out")) {
    Cycles = c(Cycles, 
    lapply(all_simple_paths(g, t, fr, mode = "out"), function(p)c(fr,p)))
  }
}

LongCycles = Cycles[which(sapply(Cycles, length) > 1)]
LongCycles[sapply(LongCycles, min) == sapply(LongCycles, `[`, 1)]
```

Does anyone have ideas? That would be helpful !!

Comment: Is this any different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997320/find-all-existed-cycles-from-data-in-r

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, it's different. The prior one I didn't know how to write codes to find any cycles. After take https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091438/r-igraph-find-all-cycles?noredirect=1&lq=1 as reference, I've already use code to find cycles.
But I'd like to calculate the amount of each cycles as above.
This one is the extension one based on the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a shorter way, but provided your data is as follows (where `h` is your table with amounts, and `all_cycles` list with cycles) -

```
h = data.frame(fr  = c('A','A','X','E','B','W','C','Y'),
               t   = c('B','E','Y','C','A','X','A','W'),
               Amt = c( 40, 30, 55, 10, 33, 78, 21, 90))

all_cycles <- list(
  c(A = 1, E = 3, C = 6, A = 1),
  c(A = 1, B = 4, A = 1),
  c(X = 2, Y = 7, W = 5, X = 2)
)
```

.. you could do:

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(
  Nodes = unlist(lapply(all_cycles, names)),
  Path = unlist(lapply(seq_along(all_cycles), 
                       function(x) rep(paste(names(all_cycles[[x]]), collapse = " - "), 
                                       length(all_cycles[[x]]))))
  ) %>%
  group_by(Path) %>%
  mutate(fr = Nodes, t = lead(Nodes)) %>%
  left_join(h) %>%
  summarise(sumAmt = sum(Amt, na.rm = TRUE), numberOfEdges = sum(!is.na(t)))
```

To get:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Path          sumAmt numberOfEdges
  <fct>          <dbl>         <int>
1 A - B - A         73             2
2 A - E - C - A     61             3
3 X - Y - W - X    223             3
```

In case first value is always unnamed in the elements of your list, you could do:

```
data.frame(
  Nodes = unlist(lapply(all_cycles, names)),
  id = unlist(lapply(seq_along(all_cycles), 
                       function(x) rep(x, length(all_cycles[[x]])))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  ) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% mutate(Nodes = replace(Nodes, Nodes == "", last(Nodes)),
                          Path = paste(Nodes, collapse = " - ")) %>%
  mutate(fr = Nodes, t = lead(Nodes)) %>%
  group_by(Path, id) %>%
  left_join(h) %>%
  summarise(sumAmt = sum(Amt, na.rm = TRUE), numberOfEdges = sum(!is.na(t)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!  But I've a little problem !!

Comment: But I've a little problem !!
I don't know why it cannot show the first  node so that I can't calculate the sum accurately. It looks as below :
*should be like : A - B - A  ; A - E - C - A
*the result in my code : "   - B - A"  ;  "    - E - C - A" 
Do you know any reason regarding this ??

Comment: @ChenHobbit this is because first value always seems to be unnamed. I've posted a workaround.