# How to measure the % of loops in a network in R?

Tags: r, networking, measure, network-analysis, sna

I am calculating some measures of a group of networks and got stuck when trying to calculate the percentage of "loops" in my networks. This is not a question about "for-loops"/"while-loops"/"repeat-loops", but on how much a node feeds into itself, trying to understand how closed it is to external nodes, if that makes sense :)

Loving some input. Thanks!
A

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your issue as it will help others answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: You might find this response to a similar question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091438/r-igraph-find-all-cycles.  It is not an easy problem if your networks are large.  The graph theory term for what you are calling loops is 'cycles' so you might have better luck searching for solutions with that jargon.