# Counting 4 and 6-cycles in bipartite R igraph

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph, cycle

I want to count the number of four-cycles and the number of six-cycles in a bipartite igraph in R. Adapting the code in [r igraph find all cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091438/r-igraph-find-all-cycles), I've come up with this solution:

```
> set.seed(1)
> library(igraph)
> G <- bipartite.random.game(10,10,p=.5)  #A random bipartite
> 
> cycles <- NULL  #List all cycles up to length 6 (2-cycles, 4-cycles, and 6-cycles)
> for(v1 in V(G)) {for(v2 in neighbors(G, v1)) {cycles <- c(cycles, lapply(all_simple_paths(G, v2, v1, cutoff = 5), function(p) c(v1,p)))}}
> fourcycles <- cycles[which(sapply(cycles, length) == 5)]  #Just four-cycles
> fourcycles <- fourcycles[sapply(fourcycles, min) == sapply(fourcycles, `[`, 1)]  #Unique four-cycles
> length(fourcycles)  #Number of four-cycles
[1] 406
> 
> sixcycles <- cycles[which(sapply(cycles, length) == 7)]  #Just six-cycles
> sixcycles <- sixcycles[sapply(sixcycles, min) == sapply(sixcycles, `[`, 1)]  #Unique six-cycles
> length(sixcycles)  #Number of six-cycles
[1] 5490
```

It works, but is impractical for even slightly larger graphs because there are potentially exponentially many cycles to enumerate. Is there a way to do this more efficiently, maybe exploiting the fact that the graph is bipartite? Thanks!

Comment: Work does seem to be active in `igraph` relevant to this: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/pull/1957, but I dont think it has been rolled out yet

Comment: @user20650 That PR is for computing a cycle basis, not for counting cycles. Counting cycles is possible with the subisomorphism finding functions but it will be slow. It will be necessary to divide by the size of the automorphism group of the cycle itself (i.e. 2*n for an n-cycle).

Comment: However, finding _induced_ cycles up to size 6 is now possible in the newly released igraph 1.3.0, as I extended the motif finder to work with undirected motifs up to 6 vertices. If you want to put in the work, you can identify all motifs that have a 6-cycle in them to be able to count even non-induced 6-cycles. This could be done by first listing all 6-motifs then using the subisomorphism functions on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count cycles using igraph's subisomorphism functions. For example, counting 5-cycles:

```
set.seed(123)
g <- sample_gnm(10,30)
```

```
> count_subgraph_isomorphisms(make_ring(5), g)
[1] 3500
```

This overcounts 5-cycles by 10 as each 5-cycle has 10 automorphisms. Generally, n-cycles have 2n automorphisms. Thus the true count is 350.

```
> automorphisms(make_ring(5))$group_size
[1] "10"
```

It will also be quite slow.

---

With the newly released igraph 1.3.0, we can use the motif finder functionality, which has now been extended to work with 5 and 6 vertex undirected graphs.

Since motifs are *induced* subgraphs, but we are looking for all cycles, not just induced ones, we first need to check how many 5-cycles each 5-motif has. Note that there are 34 non-isomorphic graphics on 5 vertices, as [you can look up e.g. in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000088). Notice also the division by 10, as before, to avoid overcounting.

```
cycle5_per_motif <- sapply(0:33, function (c) count_subgraph_isomorphisms(make_ring(5), graph_from_isomorphism_class(5, c, directed=F)) / 10)
```

With this information, we can run the motif finder and compute the final cycle count:

```
> sum(motifs(g, 5) * cycle5_per_motif, na.rm=T)
[1] 350
```

This is much faster than using `count_subgraph_isomorphisms`, but it only works up to 6-cycles at this moment.

Comment: nice answer with `count_subgraph_isomorphisms`, +1!

Comment: The solution using igraph 1.3.0 looks promising. I had trouble installing from source on a macos-arm64 , but maybe it will work once the binary is available.

Comment: @Zachary You can check if the binary is available here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/ The last one that's not yet available is exactly macOS-arm64. Hopefully it won't take more than one extra day. You're right that the requirements for compiling on macOS should be documented, but unfortunately they're a bit involved ...